# Using a prepared VirtualBox hard disk on Windows

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox 4.2.16 on Windows 7.  I'm already successfully using several Virtual Machines, however I've now downloaded an image for an old version of CentOS from www.virtualboxes.org - unzipped it, got the `.vdi` file, followed the instructions for installing a new HD, and then get the error

```
"The hard disk storage unit at location <location> already exists. You 
cannot create a new virtual hard disk that uses this location because 
it can already be used by another virtual hard disk.

Please specify another location"
```

What am I missing?!

Comment: Based on the error your attempting to load the vhdd from the same location as another vhdd with the same name.

Comment: I think that's VirtualBox errors not being very helpful - given I've downloaded a `.vdi` - if I had one of the same name I couldn't copy it in the same location anyway! I've got my new downloaded `.vdi` in its own `CentOS5` folder where it is the only file. I've made sure I am definitely selecting this file to use as a VHDD

Comment: .vdi is the virtual machine not the hdd for the virtual machine.